# Are there any javascript code (polyfill) available that enable Flexbox (2012, css3), like modernizr?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, polyfills

I'm looking for any javascript library that like modernizr (**which actually does not**) enables flexbox for "older browsers" (a **polyfill**).

Yea I know this is a really new feature (infact "there aren't" is a valid answer), but I'm hoping for something like this, I always have hard time with horizontal + vertical centering, this will really help and shorten the work.

I mean this flexbox: http://weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox/ (the newest)

Comment: Which older browsers do you want to support?

Comment: Not too **old**, I'm ok with just IE9, firefox and chrome both latest version. For older browsers, "update" is the keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be [too early](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) for this.  WebKit implemented it fairly recently, there's no hint of support in any mobile WebKit at all, Opera *just* released support for it, and Gecko's implementation is still in alpha.  IE?  Hah.

But as far as I can tell, no, there's no polyfill for the new flexbox.  [Flexie](http://flexiejs.com/) supports the old flexbox, and has a [ticket](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie/issues/34) open to support the new syntax...  maybe you could give them a hand?

You could always use the old flexbox, I suppose, but then you're obsolete out of the gate.  Sucky situation.

Comment: Yea, definitely sucky situation. I'll wait another day then I'll mark your as answer (I don't know if some developer will create it this night :P )

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to create your own.
http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/ has a section titled "Rolling Your Own Detection Code"

Basically you'll need something like this:

```
// detect CSS display:flex support in JavaScript
var detector = document.createElement("detect");
detector.style.display = "flex";
if (detector.style.display === "flex") {
    console.log("Flex is supported");
}
else
{
    console.log("Flex is not supported");
}
```

To expand on that and create a function:

```
function DetectDisplayValue(val)
{
  // detect CSS display:val support in JavaScript
  // 
  var detector = document.createElement("detect");
  detector.style.display = val;
  if (detector.style.display === val) {
    console.log("Display value: " + val + " is supported");
  }
  else
  {
      console.log("Display value: " + val + " is not supported");
  }
}
```

Comment: i believe the question is asking for a polyfill, not just to detect whether support exists

Comment: Oh I see, OP is asking for a Flexbox implementation, not for Modernizr-like detection.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I'm asking for an implementation